# ¿Cómo mostrar una variable String en un case de Switch, utilizando una array como principal?

Tags: java, selenium, java-8, java-ee

Estoy intentando sacar una array como principal (en el Switch) y crear una variable única para mostrar en los case de un switch. El problema es que la variable String del case, no me lo reconoce dándome este error: **Constant expression required**
Os paso mi código:

```
protected String[] arrayLanguages = new String[]{"Inglés", "Euskera", "Gallego", "Valenciano", "Castellano"};
protected String currentLanguage;

public String menuLanguage(String language) {
    currentLanguage = language;
    for (int i = 0; i<arrayLanguages.length;i++){
        switch (arrayLanguages[i]) {
            case "Inglés":
                for (int a = 0; a <arrayMenuAccountsLanguages.length;a++) {
                    System.out.println("dentro");
                    if (menuMyAccount.getText().contains(arrayMenuAccountsLanguages[a])) {
                        assertTrue(menuMyAccount.getText().contains(arrayMenuAccountsLanguages[a]));
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("no encontrar");
        }
    }
    return language;
}
```

Donde aparece el case 'Inglés', me gustaría añadir el String como variable pero no logro conseguirlo.

Comment: Hola, perdón, pero por más que lo leo y releo, no consigo entender que necesitas, podrías dar una explicación tipo "para un tonto", hasta donde probé, el case funciona correctamente, para lo demás necesito más de tu código.

Comment: Por otro lado el método recibe un parámetro **language**, con el se instancia **currentLanguage** y nunca se usa.

Comment: Hola @MarcePuente , ya está solucionado, necesitaba una variable final para que el case me lo acepte

Comment: Buenísimo, si tienes ganas publica la solución, y dala como aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

El error que te está dando "Constant expression required" se debe a que los valores de los casos en un switch tienen que ser constantes en tiempo de compilación.

Para solucionar el problema podes hacer lo siguiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLanguages.length; i++) {
  currentLanguage = arrayLanguages[i];
  switch (currentLanguage) {
    case "Inglés":
      for (int a = 0; a < arrayMenuAccountsLanguages.length; a++) {
        System.out.println("dentro");
        if (menuMyAccount.getText().contains(arrayMenuAccountsLanguages[a])) {
          assertTrue(menuMyAccount.getText().contains(arrayMenuAccountsLanguages[a]));
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
      System.out.println("no encontrar");
  }
}
```

Comment: El error solo me da cuando uso la variable currentLanguage al case

Comment: Si, porque el case de un switch en Java requiere una expresión constante en tiempo de compilación. Sin embargo, la variable currentLanguage es una variable que puede cambiar y no es constante, por lo que no se puede usar en un case.

Comment: Gracias me has resuelto la duda, necesitaba una variable constante

Comment: Hola @mgarciaQA la sentencia **switch( arrayLanguages[i] ) {** es correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas aquí os dejo la respuesta! @MarcePuente

```
protected static String[] arrayLanguages = new String[]{"Inglés","Euskera","Gallego","Valenciano","Castellano"};
      public String menuLanguage(String language){
        currentLanguage = language;
        for (int i = 0; i<arrayLanguages.length;i++){
            if (currentLanguage.contains(arrayLanguages[i])){
                menuAccountCardLanguage();
            } 
        }  
    return currentLanguage;
    }
```